# An interesting geometry problem with midpoints and perpendicular lines in a rectangle

Tags: geometry, rectangles

[image]

I saw this question from a student's geometry homework. And I was thinking whether there was an efficient method to solve the question.

We are  supposed to prove $DM \perp MN$.

[image]

My thinking is to draw the midpoint of AD and label it as L on AD. Next, connect LM. I was trying to use the midpoint theorem.

We know that $LM \parallel DK$. Since $DK \perp AC$, we have $LM \perp AC$.
Therefore, I just need to prove $\angle LMD = \angle NMC$. But I failed to do so.

Does anyone have a better way to prove this question?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $L$, $D$, $N$, and $C$ are concylic, since they form a rectangle.

Since you showed that $LM\perp MC$, it follows that $\angle LMC$ and $\angle LDC$ are both right angles and hence supplementary, so $M$, $L$, $D$, and $C$ are concyclic as well.

Thus, $M$, $L$, $D$, $N$, and $C$ are all concyclic. Since $DN$ is also a diameter of this circle, it follows that $\angle DMN$ must be a right angle.

Comment: Thank you!  I understand it now! It's amazing to use the property of a circle here!